Powershell: Why using 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive'`?
In a Powershell script that I found on the Internet, I came across the following command:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive

The command is used to unpack a compressed (ZIP)-File. I would have just used Expand-Archive.
Why did the author expand the path? What is the purpose and benefit of this?

That's a module-qualified command, useful to avoid invoking Expand-Archive from some other module the user might have installed

7zip is multi threaded

Thanks to Mathias R. Jessen comment here my Answer to my own question:
Invoking the complete module-qualified command uniquely addresses the module to be called. This clearly declares which module is to be used if the user is using several modules with the same name in parallel. It serves to avoid possible ambiguities.
For everyday use (and probably in 99% of all cases), this long path designation can be omitted.
However, if you generate scripts that are intent to run on unknown systems, a complete module path improves the quality of the code.
At the end of the day, it is up to the developer to decide whether he wants to accept the overhead of declaring the module in favor of code quality.

I don't think it should make a difference if you use the expanded path or not.
But it was most likely used for certainty that they were expanding the correct archive. Or possibly for over simplification in the example or tutorial you were following.
I'd be interested to hear if anyone has any other major reasons...

This sounds more like a comment than an answer :)

I don't think there is a definitive answer here. So thought that the "comment" may be the best possible answer.
But correct me if you have a better answer. ;)
